# Postgresql interval data type - trim years/mons

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql `INTERVAL` data type provides information starting from years/mons/days.

```
0 years 0 mons 7 days 3 hours 1 mins 25.00 secs
```

How to trim the details of years/mons if they have a value of 0? I need the output to be

```
7 days 3 hours 1 mins 25 secs
```

I used `date_trunc()` to trim the milliseconds value but .00 still remains. Anyway to remove that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my poor attempt.

```
    select concat_ws(' ',extract(day from now())|| ' days', 
                         extract(hours from now())|| ' hours', 
                         extract(minutes from now())|| ' mins', 
                         extract(seconds from date_trunc('second', now()::timestamp))|| ' secs');
```

```
            concat_ws            
---------------------------------
 22 days 9 hours 56 mins 53 secs
```

You can discard the .00 in that query.

Hope this somehow helps

Answer (score 0):

What about a simple LEFT?

```
 SELECT LEFT(DATE_TRUNC('hour',timestamp),13)
```

which will give the hour value and date